# Only writing to a file certain columns of a line (seperated by spaces)

Tags: python, text, file-io

I am reading a log line by line. I am trying to only print certain columns of the line. With a bash script I would use awk and $ to seperate it. However, I cant figure out how to do it with Python. I tried using split, but it doesnt do exactly what I want.

My code right now:

```
for line in file:
    if STORED_PROCS_BEGIN in line:
        log.write(line)
    elif STORED_PROCS_FINISHED in line:
        log.write(line)
    elif STORED_TASK_BEGIN in line:
        log.write(line)
    elif STORED_TASK_FINISHED in line:
        log.write(line)
    elif ACTUATE_REPORT_SCHEDULE in line:
        break
```

So when I am trying to format the line being passed into write().

Example of what I want:

date time info junk1 junk2 name => date time info name

Edit: I got an idea that I could split and extract the fields I want and them join them together.. But there has to be a better what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split a line into its words using `split()`, that's right.  Then you can index the columns you want to have in the output:

```
line = 'date time info junk1 junk2 name'
parts = line.split()
parts_I_want = parts[0:3] + parts[5:6]
print ' '.join(parts_I_want)
```

If you just want to remove some columns, you can also use `del`:

```
line = 'date time info junk1 junk2 name'
parts = line.split()
del parts[4]  # junk2
del parts[3]  # junk1
print ' '.join(parts)
```

Comment: Ah! I was trying to put all the numbers together.. like [0:1:2:5] let me try your way.

Comment: Hey so I am trying to delete certain parts of the string however its not working exactly how I want it to. So I printed my string after i split it.. Shouldnt it go [index 0, 1, 2 ...]?

Comment: The index starts with 0, yes.  Is that what you mean?  Maybe you deleted entries upwards (`del p[3]; del p[4]`) instead of downwards (`del p[4]; del p[3]`)?  Then you will delete the wrong ones.  I'm sorry, I don't really understand what you mean, so I'm fishing in the dark :-}

Comment: Yeah I was jsut wondering the order.. Yeah maybe I should go backwards.. nice

Comment: Or use `del p[3:5]` to delete elements 3 and 4.  (Slices have an offset of +1 for the end.)

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
' '.join(filter(lambda x: x not in ['junk1', 'junk2'] , line.split()))
```

Comment: I think in column 3 and 4 will not always be `'junk1`' and `'junk2'`.  The values will vary, only the column number is fix.

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding, If you want to remove particular coloumn for example 3, 4 ' '.join([x[1] for x in [(i, col) for i, col in enumerate(line.split())] if x[0] not in [3, 4]])

Answer (score 1):

Im assuming columns are spaced with tabs. 
If you really do not want to do:

```
columns = line.split("\t")
line = "\t".join(columns[:3] + columns[5:])
```

or the more compact and uglier:

```
line = "\t".join(line.split("\t")[:3] + line.split("\t")[5:])
```

...you could use regex replace:

```
line = re.sub(r'(\S+\t\S+\t\S+)\t\S+\t\S+\t(\S+)', r'\1\t\2', line)
```

\t = tab

\S+ = one or more non-whitespace letters

() = group

This groups the first four columns as reference \1 and the last column as reference \2 two and substitutes the matching expression with group 1 and two separated by a tab.

Ran in interactive python:

```
$ re.sub(r'(\S+\t\S+\t\S+)\t\S+\t\S+\t(\S+)', r'\1\t\2',line)
'date\ttime\tinfo\tname'
```